# curl : submit form data using post method in c++

Tags: magento, visual-c++, oauth, libcurl

I want to submit a simple form data from the c++ to the server using post method using libcurl. how to do that ??

My data is follows:

```
Url : http://localhost/myproject/myadmin/oauth_authorize/index/
```

Post data are follows:

```
admin_parameters=form_key=slkjdkfjd&login[username]=sdfd&login[password]=ksjdkkfd&oauth_token=kdsjkfjdkfjd
```

My CURL code:

```
        CURL *curl;
        CURLcode res;

        curl=curl_easy_init();
        if(curl)
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost/myproject/myadmin/oauth_authorize/index/");

            curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);   
            curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,admin_parameters);

            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            if(res != CURLE_OK)
            {
                strError.Format("Error: Magento Admin Login Fails.: %s", res);
            }
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        }
```

How to submit this data and get response from the server. please help me out.
Thank in advanced.

Comment: this is all explained fine in libcurl docs and examples already...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have struggled the same problem and here is the solution.

1st: You need to make sure that you entered the exact parameters and it's syntax. You can accomplish by using "Inspect element" of Chrome, choose "Network" tab and do a request to your web service.

2. From the image below, you should have use "Request URL" as the URL of your `curl`.
3. Your parameter should be presented exactly as it is in "Form Data".

2nd: By default, `curl` won't do any encode to your post data. So you have to do it yourself.

[image]

Code:

```
void request()
{
    string formData = "Your form data in plain text";

    // Encode form data
    string formDataEncoded = static_cast<string>(formData);

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if(curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "Request URL");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, formDataEncoded.c_str());
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if(res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            cout << stderr << "curl_easy_perform() failed: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << endl;
        }

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();
}
```